# Metaplex storage upload: block height exceeded

Tags: metaplex-js, arweave

we are using metaplex-foundation/js o upload files to arweave, but since a few days we run into an error block height exceeded for the fund transaction.
it seems to be related to priority fees, but apparently, there is no way to add priority fees to this transaction... any one ran into the same problem and found a solution ?

Comment: It's possible to add priority fees to any transaction, the JS package just needs to be updated to support it!